# How to outsource asyncData to Vuex Store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm currently loading some data from firebase I wan't to be server side rendered so it can be indexed for SEO in `asyncData` on a page.

```
asyncData() {
  return firebase.firestore().collection('Programms').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    const programms = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const programm = doc.data();
        programm.id = doc.id;
        programms.push(programm)
    })
    return { programms: programms};
  })
```

However I would like to convert this to my vuex store.

I know I could do this:

```
const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
        firebase.firestore().collection('Programms').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const programms = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const programm = doc.data();
                programm.id = doc.id;
                programms.push(programm)
            })
            console.log('loaded Programms', programms)

            commit('setProgramms', programms);
        })
    },
}
```

But this way the data will be loaded for every route in my app. I wan't to load this data only in some pages where I also display it, so I don't load it unnecessary.

How could I do this in Vuex?

Comment: Need some more information as of how you're calling this data since you said you don't want to load it on every router?

Comment: Not sure what I should provide you. On some (currently only 1) page,  I have this `asyncData`. However I want to handle my data not in the components, so I want to outsource this in a vuex store. However `nuxtServerInit` would load it for every page/route, so also for pages I don't need it.

Comment: I guess. First, you need to create routes and check if the data is loaded or not then you can add the example with all the relevant code.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I need exactly. I'm using Nuxt.js and Server Side Rendering. AsyncData runs before the client takes over from the server.

Comment: use fetch method instead of asyncdata 7 is it what u are looking for 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @aldarund says, the fetch method is precisely what you want.

```
fetch ({ store, params }) {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('Programms').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    const programms = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const programm = doc.data();
        programm.id = doc.id;
        programms.push(programm)
    })
    .then(() => {
      store.commit('setPrograms', programms)
    })
  }
```

See the docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/).

Comment: The fetch method deosn't work for some reason. I posted my vuex store in my post. Any Ideas?